# How to call ajax function on buttonclick in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

View Code:

```
<script>
    function getMessage(){
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/getmsg',
           data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
           success:function(data){
              $("#msg").html(data.msg);
           }
        });
     }
</script>


<body>
     <div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. Click the button to replace the message.</div>
     <input type="button" value="Replace Message" onclick='getMessage()'>
</body>
```

Here ,When I click on the button it should be replaced by the other text. But nothings appears on clicking.

Controller code:

```
public function index(){
    $msg = "This is a simple message.";
    return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
}
```

Comment: Actually, this question has nothing to do with laravel, but javascript and jquery

Comment: I am just using this for learning ajax

Comment: Can we see your route file? I'm adamant the problem is you're not getting to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In pure js that code work fine

```js
     function getMessage(){
        alert('Its working!');
     }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. 
     Click the button to replace the message.</div>


  <input type="button" value="Replace Message" onclick='getMessage()'>
</body>
```

Comment: No!!I need ajax call

Comment: @Suryakala So you have troubles with ajax request not with button click, add error handler to your call and inspect exception then:  `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                }`

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax code you didn't define `dataType`, add `dataType:"json",` to retrive the json data, change your ajax code as
 function getMessage(){

```
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'/getmsg',
     dataType:'json',
     data:{
         _token = '<?php echo csrf_token() ?>'
     },
     success:function(data){
         $("#msg").html(data.msg);
     }
});
```

Comment: Nothing happens sir!

Comment: @Suryakala check it now, you are not passing data in right way

Comment: No errors were displayed SIR!!. It simply shows up the view page with the button. But when clicking on the button nochange occurs

Comment: are u uploaded the jquery before calling your script?

Comment: Actually,I have taken those code from laravel tutorials. THere I have replaced the code -- <?php
         echo Form::button('Replace Message',['onClick'=>'getMessage()']);
      ?>--    with <input type="button" value="Replace Message" onclick='getMessage()'>

Comment: <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
      </script>      This is what I used in my view

Comment: use this, before your script `<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`, and remove the upper jquery you uploaded

Answer (score -1):

Update your code with below mentioned code, and let's try.. i will working for me..

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).on('click', '#btnSelector', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */

        getMessage();

    });
    var getMessage = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/getmsg', //Make sure your URL is correct
            dataType: 'json', //Make sure your returning data type dffine as json
            data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data); //Please share cosnole data
                if(data.msg) //Check the data.msg isset?
                {
                    $("#msg").html(data.msg); //replace html by data.msg
                }

            }
        });
    }
 </script>

<body>

    <div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. Click the button to replace the message.</div>
    <input type="button" value="Replace Message" id='btnSelector'>

</body>
```

Comment: Sorry sir!!Nothing happens. I don't know what the mistake is!!

Comment: I have updated the answer..., change the onclick event to event listner..., Please try with...!! Also share you `console.log(data)` value...

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
     <div id='msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. Click the button to replace the message.</div>
     <input type="button" id="ajax_call" value="Replace Message">
</body>
<script>
   $(function () {
      $('#ajax_call').on('click', function () {
         $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo url("/getms"); ?>',
            data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
            success:function(data){
               $("#msg").html(data.msg);
            },
            complete: function(){
               alert('complete');
            },
            error: function(result) {
               alert('error');
            }
         });
      });
   });
</script>
```

Jquery onclick function: [jquery onclick function not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292763/jquery-onclick-function-not-defined/#answer-44292802)

Also check: [Function not calling within an onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242541/function-not-calling-within-an-onclick-event/#answer-4242572)